# Independent events in Probability theory

Tags: probability-theory, independence, provability

Events A, B and C are independent, $\mathbb P (A) = 0.1$; $\mathbb P (B) = 0.4$ and $\mathbb P (C) = 0.9.$

1. Find the probability of an event $D = (A + B) (A + C) (B + C).$
2. Find the probability of event D if it is known that event A has already occurred.

At first glance, the task seemed easy and I used the multiplication and addition formulas for the probabilities:

I) $\mathbb P(A+B)= \mathbb P(A) + \mathbb P(B)$

II) $P(A\cdot\ B) = \mathbb P(A) \cdot\ \mathbb P(\frac{B}{A}) $

1. $D=(0,1+0,4)*(0,1+0,7)*(0,4+0,7)=0,44$
2. $D=(1+0,4)*(1+0,7)*(0,4+0,7)=2,618$

but the answer came out wrong, this is on the first point. The second point, I took probability A as a unit and also used the formulas for adding and multiplying the probabilities, but the answer is also incorrect. Why? What is the highlight of this task?

Correct answer:

1. 0.4180.
2. 0.940.

Comment: Please edit to include your efforts.  Include your calculation (even if it is incorrect).

Comment: Please show what you have done so that we can point out where the errors are.

Comment: Okay, just a second

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following Venn's Diagram

[image]

(1) what they are requesting you is to calculate the probability of the event

$$D=(A \cup B)\cap(A \cup C)\cap(B \cup C)$$

that is the probability of the purple area:

$$0.1\times0.4+0.1\times 0.9+0.4\times0.9-2\times0.1\times0.4\times0.9=0.418$$

(2) Can you  try to proceed by yourself? (the previous diagram can be **VERY** useful)

after a small reasoning you get

$$\mathbb{P}(D|A)=\frac{\mathbb{P}(AD)}{\mathbb{P}(A)}=\frac{\mathbb{P}(AB)+\mathbb{P}(AC)-\mathbb{P}(ABC)}{\mathbb{P}(A)}=$$

$$=\frac{0.1\times0.4+0.1\times0.9-0.1\times0.4\times0.9}{0.1}=0.94$$

this because $A\cap D$ is the following area

[image]

that means its probability is $P(AB)+P(AC)-P(ABC)$

Comment: Why here $0.1×0.4+0.1×0.9+0.4×0.9−2×0.1×0.4×0.9=0.418$ we minus this$2×0.1×0.4×0.9$?

Comment: Can you please explain your reasoning and how you got the formula for calculating the probability when event A has already happened?

Comment: @Ben : could you please spend a second to accept my answer? Anyway I edited my answer

Comment: Could you answer to my last question why you wrote this one −2×0.1×0.4×0.9?

Comment: @Ben : to avoid double counting probabilities

Comment: I got it, thank you!

Comment: Could i ask one more question?

Comment: @Ben yes, you can

Comment: If we change our expression in D as $D=(A+B')(B+C')(C+A'), $ all other conditions are the same and the meanings are the same. I tried using your method to draw a Venn diagram and use it to compose a formula and calculate, but the answer is still incorrect. What can this be connected with?

Comment: @Ben : the method is always valid. If your answer is incorrect it means that you applied it incorrectly. I think you can post a new question, including your efforts to solve the problem, as usual

Comment: **Here is my diagram** [link](https://www4c.wolframalpha.com/Calculate/MSP/MSP164815fei5fad3dcg9hh00001e8hd48f66dgii9d?MSPStoreType=image/gif&s=50&w=220.&h=212.&cdf=Resizeable)

Comment: Okay, I understand